# Team Build vs MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, tfsbuild

can some one explain the difference between Team Build + MSBuild ?

also how do they differ in relation to VS2008 and VS2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Team Foundation Build provides the functionality of a public build lab and is part of Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181710%28VS.80%29.aspx

MSBuild is a platform for building applications.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx